# How to select current and next values after applying filters

Tags: mysql

I'm looking into selecting the next time a timestamp pops up but it shouldn't be within 60 minutes after the previous time stamp.

MySQL 5.6.32-78.1

Current Result

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | prev_time  | next_time  |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 101 | 100001     | 100059     |
| 101 | 100059     | 100061     |
| 101 | 100061     |   NULL     |
| 102 | 100030     | 100035     |
| 102 | 100035     | 100090     |
| 102 | 100090     |   NULL     |
| 103 | 100005     | 100115     |
| 103 | 100115     |   NULL     |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

I want to show like this:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | prev_time  | next_time  |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 101 | 100001     | 100061     |
| 102 | 100030     | 100090     |
| 103 | 100005     | 100115     |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

This is my current code to show next_time

```
(
    SELECT
    MIN(so1.date_created)

    FROM ecms.customer c1
    LEFT JOIN ecms.sales_order so1 ON so1.customer_id = c1.id
    WHERE c1.id = c.id
    AND so1.date_created > so.date_created
    AND IF((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(so.date_created, so1.date_created))/360)>=60,1,0) = 1
) as next_time
```

The results return a NULL.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, perhaps you could clarify and tell what version of mysql

Comment: Sorry. I'm using mysql Workbench 6.3

I want to query the next time where value is greater than or equal to 60 minutes.

Comment: Workbench is just a frontend. Run the query `select version();` to get the servers version. Apart from that, I don't get it either. Your current result is a simple `select * from table;`? Describe why your desired result looks the way it is. Why is the very first row not included? Looks like `less than 60` to me. And so on...

Comment: Hi, I think this is clearer? :) I just wanna know how I can skip any timestamp less than 60 so the next_time should be after 60 from prev_time